# Recursive regex for validating ranges

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, recursion

I'm making a printing system and in a certain moment I need to use a recursive regular expression for validating the onkeypress of an input, allowing that it be accepted only if it match that regular expression. But this is a recursive expression!

Some valid data:

```
[0]: "1-9"
[1]: "1"
[2]: "1-9,1"
[3]: "1,1-9,2,1-8"
```

It would be very easy in EBNF:

```
validation = ( number ) | ( number, '-', number ), ',', validation ;
number = digit, { digit } ;
digit = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 0 ;
```

But regex doesn't follow the same approach as EBNF does. I've read about recursive regular expressions but I'm still confused about them. My current non-recursive attempt, that validates 1/1 of each comma-splitted valid value:

```
/([0-9]*)|(([0-9]*)-([0-9]*))/g
```

This way I can validated each entry individually, but I figure out a way to validate all the content.

A temporary solution is:

```
pattern = /([0-9]*)|(([0-9]*)-([0-9]*))/g
fields = fieldValues.split(',')
```

And I was creating an array containing true or false to know if the expression matches. Can't I do it all in a regex, free of JavaScript?

Comment: This regex is not recursive at all.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: The output should be just a boolean value. TRUE || FALSE.

Comment: Ok, so we've established you want to match `<something>`, and return `true` or `false`. What should return `true`? The "valid data" block in your question?

Comment: @TonyCamargo you mean this http://regex101.com/r/dT6dN8/4 ?

Comment: Is it just me, or is there some trend towards trying to solve every known string parsing, transformation and validation problem in the world by using humongous, unreadable, unmaintainable regexps? There are so many other ways to go--splitting, scanning, parsing with your own micro-parser, parsing with a parsing library, you name it. The maintainability problems are all the scarier when you consider that in the majority of "write me a regexp" questions on SO, the OP appears not to clearly understand, or at least not be able to articulate, what rules he or she is trying to write a regexp for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want something like this,

```
> /^\d+(?:-\d+)?(,\d+(?:-\d+)?)*$/.test("1-9,1");
true
> /^\d+(?:-\d+)?(,\d+(?:-\d+)?)*$/.test("1-9,1,");
false
> /^\d+(?:-\d+)?(,\d+(?:-\d+)?)*$/.test("1-9,1-1");
true
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this regular expression:

```
/^\d+(?:(?:-\d+(?:,\d+)?)*|(?:,\d+(?:-\d+)?)*)$/
```

Here is an explanation:

- `^` and `$` asserts start and end of the match.
- `(?: )` group has `|` alternation, to match either:
- `\d+` (optional `-\d+` optional `,\d+`) once or more, or;
- `\d+` (optional `,\d+` optional `-\d+`) once or more.

Here is a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/jW8yS9/2).

Answer (score 1):

What about?

```
([0-9]+|([0-9]+-[0-9]+))(,([0-9]+|([0-9]+-[0-9]+)))*
```

Or with the \d character class shorthand notation:

```
(\d+|(\d+-\d+))(,(\d+|(\d+-\d+)))*
```

Explanation:

This is the basic pattern

```
(\d+|(\d+-\d+))
```

Optionally followed (zero or more times) by character ","  and the same pattern, again. Hence:

```
(,(\d+|(\d+-\d+)))*
```